# Verilog multipler won't compile

Tags: verilog

I have this code and it was producing a GTK wave early but I had to make it RTL from behavioral but now it won't compile. If any one could help me figure this out I'm getting errors:

- main.v:31: error: malformed statement
- main.v:26: error: Error in for loop step assignment
- main.v:26: syntax error
- main.v:30: syntax error
- main.v:30: error: malformed statement
- main.v:31: syntax error

Here is my code:

```
module combinational_mult(product,multiplier,multiplicand);
input [31:0] multiplier;
 input [63:0] multiplicand;
 output product;

reg [63:0] product;
reg c;
reg [63:0] m;
 integer i;

 always @( multiplier or multiplicand )
 begin
//initialize
 product[63:32] = 32'b0;
 product[31:0] = multiplier;
 m = multiplicand;
c = 1'b0;

//add,shift algorithm  for unsigned multiplication.
//following the notes.
// for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1)
// begin
//if(product[0]) {c,product[63:32]} = product[31:16] + m ;
//product[63:0] = {c,product[63:1]};
                //  c = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    begin
     if (multiplier == 1)
            product = product + m;
            multiplicand << 1;
            multiplier >> 1;
            c=0;
    end

 end
endmodule

module testbench;
 reg [31:0] multiplier;
 reg [63:0] multiplicand;

initial begin
  $dumpfile("USAMv1.dat");
  $dumpvars;

  #10ns;
  multiplier   = 32'b0000_0000_0000_0000_1101_1001_1101_1001;
  multiplicand = 32'b0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_1010_1101_1000;

  #50ns;
  multiplier   = 32'b0;
  multiplicand = 32'b0;

  $finish;
end

combinational_mult dut ( product, multiplier, multiplicand);
endmodule
```

Comment: Most modern tools will interpret as SystemVerilog if you have a .sv file extension instead of .v.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog does not support `++` (SystemVerilog does), use `i=i+1`.

The shifter operators (`<<` & `>>`) need to be part of a right hand expression an assignment. Ex `a = b << c;`

<sub>*I'm only pointing out the compiling errors. Not the functional errors*</sub>

Comment: verilog supports ++ operators

Comment: @RohanPiplani ++ is not listed in the IEEE1364 as a Verilog operator. The only place in the LRM that mentions ++ is inside PLI examples (C code). Modern Verilog simulators are really SystemVerilog simulator which does support ++, but a good simulator will at least give a warning about using SV features in .v file (assuming you didn’t force SV to be enabled, which is a bad practice). Occasionally vendors have added support for features outside LRM, in which case it it not compliant with the standard and the code might not work on other simulators, synthesizers, or other tools.